AES-256 cbc encryption implementation
I'm really confused as for the CBC approach for AES.
After I encrypt every block (i use an integer array), i append the values into a string.
(the values are not lead by 0) so an example would look somethign like this

136121971222102267918144219237147211110145241 -> 61a9a853e9101d1aafd9306c03cf6083ddcd9

After appending these values, I cast these into an int, and print it as a hex number.
After this procedure, I should get a message with a length of a multiple of 16, yet I get a different amount of bytes and it varies. The values are also incorrect, which shouldnt happen.
This is a part of my encryption function
assert(val.size() == 16);

auto plain_state = parseVectorToMatrix(val);
add_round_key(plain_state, keyMatrix[0]);

for (uint8_t i = 1; i < nround; i++) {
    sub_bytes(plain_state);
    shift_rows(plain_state);
    mix_columns(plain_state);
    add_round_key(plain_state, keyMatrix[i]);
}

sub_bytes(plain_state);
shift_rows(plain_state);
add_round_key(plain_state, keyMatrix[keyMatrix.size() - 1]);

and this is the cbc chaining
for (auto block : splitToBlocks(plain_text)) {
    auto xord = xorBytes(block, prevCipher);
    auto cipher_block = encrypt(xord);

    blocks.push_back(cipher_block);
    prevCipher = cipher_block;
}

Is there anything wrong with my logic? I'm really confused.

I've closed this question as it doesn't provide enough information to debug the problem. The given answer is not wrong but it can only provide hints on what could be wrong. To debug an implementation there needs to be access to the relevant source code and tests / test vectors. As a hint, I would urge you to check intermediate values from other implementations to see where your code goes wrong.

To see why hexadecimals don't print please try and find solutions on SO or ask a question there. [crypto.se] is not for solving generic programming problems.


After appending these values, I cast these into an int, and print it as a hex number. After this procedure, I should get a message with a length of a multiple of 16, yet I get a different amount of bytes and it varies.

Almost certainly there's something wrong in your 'cast into an int and print it as a hex number' procedure.
It could be that you're trying to cast a value that's too big to fit into an int; it could be that your printing process skips leading 0's (which can most certainly happen).
Without seeing the code that does this, it's impossible to say for sure.

Well, I'm using Boost's CPP_INT in order to handle bigger numbers, so overflow shouldn't be an issue.
Also, am I not supposed to ignore leading 0's? this doesnt really make sense since its kinda useless

@DayDrunk: as for ignoring leading 0's, if AES generates the ciphertext block 0123456789sbcdef0123456789abcdef, and you print it out as 123456789sbcdef0123456789abcdef, well, that would explain your problem.

Well, its more the incorrect values that flip me off, I'm supposed to get C079... and i get 61a9..

Well, the 'wrong number of bytes' and 'incorrect values' are likely due to different causes.  If you want to track the 'incorrect values' first, the first thing to do is check out your AES implementation.  FIPS 197 has good test vectors (for the key expansion and for 128-bit encryption) - you might want to compare the internal values your implementation gets with those.
